# Qt Creator debug doesn't stop at breakpoint directly

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qt-creator

As the pic I show here.

[image: debug pic]

I set a breakpoint at the line

```
w.show();
```

However, when I press F5 to debug. It doesn't stop at this line directly.
It stop to other lines in other files which I haven't set breakpoint many times. After that it stop at the line which I have set breakpoint. It is a waste of time. Why debug doesn't stop at breakpoint directly?

Comment: Try to compile with the lowest optimization level `-O0`. Maybe the code is being optimize and it doesn't look as you would expect.

Comment: One of the reasons can be that your current code does not correspond to one your executable was compiled with. Try to recompile the project (force).

Comment: I tried, but no work! @WooWapDaBug

Comment: I tried, but no work! @vahancho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my question. Just clear all the breakpoints in all project. Although there is just one breakpoint in my testing project